# What do the brackets mean in this TypeScript Lambda Expression?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lambda, ecmascript-6

I am reading a book about Angular but I can't find any documentation about this brackets usage for the lambda expression `[hours, rate]) => this.total = hours * rate`. Although I understand that I can use these parameters (hours and rate) from inside the body of the lambda expression. I don't understand why this `(hours, rate) => this.total = hours * rate)` doesn't work and why do I have to use the brackets [].

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.invoiceForm.get('hours').valueChanges,
this.invoiceForm.get('rate').valueChanges).subscribe(
  ([hours, rate]) => this.total = hours * rate);
```

Can somebody explain me what it means and where I can find documentation about that usage.

Note: I know what combineLatest does what I don't understand is the lambda expression usage with those brackets.

Comment: It means that the parameter is an array with 2 items and the items will be "destructured" (see @t.niese answer) as follows - 1st item to variable `hours`, 2nd to variable `rate`. If the array is longer, then `rate` will contain the array without the 1st item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is like the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
function test([a, b]) {
  console.log(a, ',', b)

}

test([1, 2])
```

The `[a, b]` is the one parameter of your function. And if an array is passed as first argument to the function, then the first element of the array will be stored in `a` and the second one in  `b`.

Answer (score 0):

combineLatest rx operator:

When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: I know what combineLatest means what I don't understand is the brackets for the lambda expression.

Comment: Brackets mean Array, we are accepting values that combineLatest emits as valuepairs represented as array. In case of more params combineLatest(a,b,c) , you would have 3 number of params as emitted value inside of those brackets.